# Ember.js, FontAwesome & Sass

Tags: ember.js, sass, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have an Ember.js project where I use Fontawesome5 and Sass. Creating an icon is easy with `<FaIcon @icon="..."/>`. But now I want to use an icon from Fontawesome with Sass (more specifically with `list-style`). I guess I could use the way it is described in the [fontawesome-sass-documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/sass), but this feels wrong in more than one way.

I tried to create a route get-icon, that I could use with `list-style: url(...)`, but as far as I see that can't work with ember.js.

So is there a preferred way to get a fontawesome icon for list-style in an ember project?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using the official font awesome library for Ember.js: `@fortawesome/ember-fontawesome` It provides the `<FaIcon>` component you mentioned.

`@fortawesome/ember-fontawesome` does not provide integration to use the SASS styles. There is an [open feature request as an issue on its GitHub repository](https://github.com/FortAwesome/ember-fontawesome/issues/140) but it hasn't received any response yet.

I assume that you are using [`ember-cli-sass`](https://github.com/adopted-ember-addons/ember-cli-sass) to integrate SASS in your build process. It's the de facto standard in Ember community as fa as I'm aware.

`ember-cli-sass` has an `includePaths` option, which allows to import SASS files from other folders than `app/styles`. You can use this option to inlcude the required SASS files in your build and import the required SASS files in your `app/styles/app.scss`.

`ember-cli-sass` documentation [includes an example](https://github.com/adopted-ember-addons/ember-cli-sass#example) how to do so for foundation CSS framework. You can use that one as a starting point.